# Best tool for cracking SHA-1s with unique pre and post salts?

Tags: passwords, hash, password-cracking, salt, sha

I can't find a tool that supports cracking SHA-1s with different pre and post salts. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are both of the salts different for every hash? Or is one of them the same for the all and the other different per hash?

Comment: I think your real question is how to do this with any tool, instead of a recommendation for a specific tool. As your question is now it asks for a product recommendation, which is off-topic here. Also, it would be nice if you show that you have tried something to solve your problem yourself.

Comment: Concur that there is abstract security value in *parts* of the question, because prepending *and* appending isn't covered well by existing tools, for reasons that are informative. But the question would need to be reworked to avoid the product-recommendation angles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John the ripper (current bleeding-edge community version), can handle this easily.  Simply use the command line switch   `--format=dynamic=sha1($s.$p.$s2)`  (note the single quotes are required), and it can easily handle the data.  you WILL have to put the data into proper input format for this to be read by the dynamic format within john.

Ok, here is an example listing how you will have to format the input data:

```
salt=e0b88e64
salt2= 35644f9d
password=passweird
```

```
input hash file (inp):
@dynamic=sha1($s.$p.$s2)@6fedfebd8127ad6c10ddb25e8584f4d24412259e$e0b88e64$$235644f9d
```

```
wordlist file  (pw)
abc
password
passweird
something_else
```

Now running the command:

```
$ ../run/john '--format=dynamic=sha1($s.$p.$s2)' --wordlist=pw inp
Using default input encoding: UTF-8
Loaded 1 password hash (dynamic=sha1($s.$p.$s2) [128/128 SSE2 4x1])
Warning: no OpenMP support for this hash type, consider --fork=2
Press 'q' or Ctrl-C to abort, almost any other key for status
Warning: Only 4 candidates left, minimum 24 needed for performance.
passweird        (?)
1g 0:00:00:00 DONE (2019-02-28 11:08) 8.264g/s 33.05p/s 33.05c/s 33.05C/s abc..something_else
Use the "--show --format=dynamic=sha1($s.$p.$s2)" options to display all of the cracked passwords reliably
Session completed
```

This shows the password being found.  Note, for john to properly read the data, it will have to be formatted similar to what I show in the 'inp' file for this example hash.

John (current bleeding jumbo), can be found at: https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper